# Query Failing, tried it 100 ways can't figure out why, can someone take a look please?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sql_ba = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO buyer_accounting VALUES '', '10', 'mel', '8', 'sept142015', '120.00', 'none', '1'");
```

> Error: Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''20', '10', 'mel', '8', 'sept142015', '120.00', 'none', '1'' at line 1

I have tried it a hundred ways from Sunday and I always get the same error

Edit: This is what the code looks like after correction;

```
$sql_ba = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO buyer_accounting (id, buyer_id, name, bp_used, auction_id, tax_collected, tax_id, pd) VALUES ('', '$buyer_num', '$b_info[0]', '$bp', '$auction_id', '$tax', '$tax_id', '1')");
```

Comment: You need to put your parameters between parenthesis

Comment: The manual is always a great place to start http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty believing that you tried 100 different ways of querying, given your other db-related questions.

Comment: Plus, we have no idea what your MySQL API looks like in regards to connecting and if you're still using `mysql_` to start with and to connect with, as per your other questions.

Comment: Well Fred this is what the code looks like after correct... $sql_ba = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO buyer_accounting (id, buyer_id, name, bp_used, auction_id, tax_collected, tax_id, pd) VALUES ('', '$buyer_num', '$b_info[0]', '$bp', '$auction_id', '$tax', '$tax_id', '1')"); and was where I started, albeit it had an error somewhere, so yes I had tried it a hundred different ways... it was called stripping to find an elusive error... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parenthesis to your statement:

```
$sql_ba = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO buyer_accounting VALUES ('', '10', 'mel', '8', 'sept142015', '120.00', 'none', '1')");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to be explicit. You also forgot to add parenthesis in your query.

```
$sql_ba = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO buyer_accounting (COLUMN-NAMES-HERE) 
                       VALUES ('', '10', 'mel', '8', 'sept142015', '120.00', 'none', '1')");
```

and replacing `COLUMN-NAMES-HERE` with your actual column names.

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html

Comment: I have done that, it failed as well, with the same exact error. See above about parenthesis, it just changed the error I got.

Comment: Great. Share the code that you have tried. Otherwise, it's hard to see what you did wrong.

Comment: The code I tried was copied and pasted from the above comment... As well I am not going to go back and try thing I have already tried just to prove someone wrong... I have been working on this for an hour, when I say I have tried it hundreds of way, I really am not kidding.

Comment: Remember that you're the one that needs help here. Help me, help you. If you say you've tried something yet are still getting an error, there's a reason for that, no? Good luck.

Comment: Yes, Chris I understand that, but I also know what I have tried and what has failed. Rehashing failed queries that give the exact same error as the one posted is a waste of time, mine and yours.

Answer (score 0):

try this add '(' in your query like this

```
INSERT INTO buyer_accounting VALUES ('', '10', 'mel', '8', 'sept142015', '120.00', 'none', '1'");
```

Comment: Error just changed... Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: "INSERT INTO buyer_accounting VALUES ('', '10', 'mel', '8', 'sept142015', '120.00', 'none', '1')"); 

try this. sorry i did not see the double quote

Comment: That worked THANK YOU!! But tell me this, what was it in the original code? LOL

Comment: you don't have the parenthesis